# Remote starting applications interactively

Tags: remote-desktop

I have an application that wouldn't start via Remote Desktop (it checks whether it was started via Windows Terminal Services). One simple way to circumvent this would be using a different remote desktop application, such as DameWare. This works, but I was wondering if I could keep using windows Remote Desktop, starting the application remotely by other means. So far I haven't been able to do so:

- PsExec / BeyondExec / Windows Scheduled Tasks - The application detects these as well (I assume they use Terminal services too)
- Telnet - The telnet session does not appear to be interactive, I can't see any of the applications I start there in my remote desktop session

I suppose I could always roll my own simple "remote process runner" (with say .NET/WCF), just wondering if there is something ready-made.

**EDIT** Rolling my own didn't work either, since I had to run the server application I built from Remote Desktop, and any process it spawned was still under that context

Comment: I was wondering if you tried a `run as` to change the user to a local one.  Also, if the roll your own was a service running on the remote box. That way it would also use a local user account. Perhaps `REMOTE.EXE` would help. Also, I don't know if VNC be acceptable.  If I knew more on how the target app protected itself from remote execution, maybe I could give better suggestions.

Comment: Strictly speaking, *all* interactive sessions, even local ones, now run via Terminal Services on XP and above.

Comment: @Scott: What I rolled was a process running on the remote box, but I ran it from the remote desktop session. As per your suggestion I also tried `run as` with a local user, still woudln't start. Perhaps it simply recognizes that the current session is a remote desktop session ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Task Scheduler as long as you have a user logged into session 1.  Remote desktop won't do this, it will create a new session, number 2, and display your desktop there.  Only remote tools like VNC or TeamViewer will connect to the desktop in session 1.

I am suspecting that, when you created the Task Schedule you started it with the user who was logged in to the Remote desktop session and task manager tried to start it in session 2 therefore it failed.

You create a scheduled task with no triggers and as the user who is logged in to session 1.  If there isn't a user in session 1, then you have to make one somehow,  I only know how to do this with an auto login.

I know that this isn't ideal, but it's the only working solution I know of.